# T-SQL Query to convert rows to coumns based on mutiple tables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have two master tables `CompanyMaster`, `ActivityMaster` for a child table `CompanyActivities`

`ActivityMaster`

```
ACTIVITYID   ACTIVITYNAME
A1           testActivity
A2           someActivity
A3           otheractivity
A4           someotheractivity
A5           anyotheractivity
```

`CompanyMaster`

```
COMPANYID  COMPANYNAME
C1         testcompany
C2         ACompany
C3         MyCompany
C4         SomeCompany
C5         ZCompany
C6         Company123
C7         ComapnyABC
```

`CompanyActivities` - The `COMPANYID` in `CompanyActivities` is having a primarykey-foreighkey relation ship with `COMPANYID` in `CompanyMaster` (primary key table) and   `ACTIVITYID` is having a primarykey-foreighkey relation ship with `ACTIVITYID` in `ActivityMaster`(primary key table)

```
COMPANYID   ACTIVITYID
C1          A1
C1          A3
C3          A1
C3          A2
C4          A5
C5          A1
C6          A3
C7          A3
```

I want to do write a query to get the following output where all the rows in `ACTIVITYID` column of the `ActivityMaster` table will be converted to columns

Output

```
Companies  A1   A2  A3  A4  A5
C1         Y    N   Y   N   N
C2         N    N   N   N   N
C3         Y    Y   N   N   N
C4         N    N   N   N   Y
C5         Y    N   N   N   N
C6         N    N   Y   N   N
C7         N    N   Y   N   N
```

The output table displays all the companies as rows in the first column and all the activities are shown as columns that start after the first column, if there is row that contains both `ACTIVITYID` and `COMPANYID` it will set to `Y` in output otherwise it would be set to `N`

eg- `COMPANYID` `C1` is having an activity `ACTIVITYID` `A1` in `CompanyActivities` table so the first row in the second column that comes just below `A1` and in the right to `C1` is set `Y`, whereas `C1` and `A2` are not having a row, so the third column in the first row is set to `N`

I am using C#.net and 4 for loops to achieve the output now which is talking a heavy toll on the performance of the application, So i would like to do this using a query, I have searched for pivot queries, but all the examples i found knows the column names before-hand, which i don't i only get the names of the column names by querying the `ActivityMaster`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table #CompanyMaster (COMPANYID int, COMPANYNAME varchar(30))
create table #ActivityMaster (ACTIVITYID int, ACTIVITYNAME varchar(30))
create table #CompanyActivities (COMPANYID int, ACTIVITYID int)

insert into #CompanyMaster
    SELECT 1, 'Company A'
    union all
    SELECT 2, 'Company B'

insert into #ActivityMaster
    SELECT 101, 'Activity X'
    union all
    SELECT 102, 'Activity Y'    
    union all
    SELECT 103, 'Activity Z'    

insert into #CompanyActivities      
    select 1, 102
    union all
    select 2, 101

-- build activities column names
--case [Activity X] when 0 then ''N'' else ''Y'' end as [Activity X],
--case [Activity Y] when 0 then ''N'' else ''Y'' end as [Activity Y],
--case [Activity Z] when 0 then ''N'' else ''Y'' end as [Activity Z]
declare @activities nvarchar(max)
set @activities
   = (
    select 'case [' + ACTIVITYNAME + '] when 0 then ''N'' else ''Y'' end as [' + ACTIVITYNAME + '],' + char(10)
    from #ActivityMaster
    for xml path('')
   )
set @activities = substring(@activities, 0, len(@activities)-1)

declare @activities_for nvarchar(max)
-- build activities column names in for
--[Activity X], [Activity Y], [Activity Z]
set @activities_for
   = (
    select '[' + ACTIVITYNAME + '],' + char(10)
    from #ActivityMaster
    for xml path('')
   )
set @activities_for = substring(@activities_for, 0, len(@activities_for)-1)


declare @sql nvarchar(MAX) = N'
select COMPANYNAME,
    <activities>
From
    (select c.COMPANYNAME, a.ACTIVITYNAME,
        (case 
            when ca.ACTIVITYID is not null and ca.COMPANYID is not null then 1
            else 0
        end) as STATUS
    from #CompanyMaster c
    cross join #ActivityMaster a
    left join #CompanyActivities ca on ca.COMPANYID = c.COMPANYID and a.ACTIVITYID = ca.ACTIVITYID)  p
pivot
    (
        sum(STATUS) for ACTIVITYNAME IN (<activities_for>)
    ) as pvt
'


set @sql = replace(@sql, '<activities>', @activities)
set @sql = replace(@sql, '<activities_for>', @activities_for)

print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql

drop table #CompanyMaster
drop table #ActivityMaster
drop table #CompanyActivities
```

Comment: That was really great, thank you, wish i could give more than +1

Comment: Welcome, you might want to order the activities "columns", add order by when those two variables are set